# differentiability of a function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Let $f$ be a continuous function on an open interval in $\mathbb R$ such that $|f|$ is differentiable. Can we show that $f$ is differentiable? I can get several examples of non-differentiable $f$ if $f$ is not continuous. But here I am stuck. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take any point $x_0$ in that interval. If $f(x_0)>0$, then, by continuity of $f$, there exists a small neighbourhood $(x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon)$ on which $f$ is strictly positive and hence $|f|=f$ on this neighbourhood, and therefore $f$ is differentiable in $x_0$. A similar reasoning can be done for the case $f(x_0)<0$.

The only interesting case is when $f(x_0)=0$. We know that the following limit converges: $$\lim _{h\to 0} \frac{|f(x_0+h)|}{h}.$$ Given that $h$ can be of abitrary sign, we conclude that this limit is zero, hence $$ f'(x_0)  = \lim _{h\to 0} \frac{ f(x_0+h) }{h}  =0,$$
and therefore we can say that a continuous function $f$ with differentiable $|f|$ is itself differentiable.

**edit by request from @skyking**

$|f|$ is differentiable, hence left and right derivatives in $x_0$ are the same:
$$\lim _{h\to 0} \frac{|f(x_0+h)|}{h}=\lim _{h\to 0,\,h>0} \frac{|f(x_0+h)|}{h}=\lim _{h\to 0,\,h<0} \frac{|f(x_0+h)|}{h}.$$
Yet, if $h>0$, then $\frac{|f(x_0+h)|}{h}\ge 0$ and $\lim _{h\to 0,\,h>0} \frac{|f(x_0+h)|}{h}\ge 0$.

Similarly, for $h<0$ we have $\frac{|f(x_0+h)|}{h}\le 0$ and $\lim _{h\to 0,\,h<0} \frac{|f(x_0+h)|}{h}\le 0$.

These two inequalities imply that the only possible value of derivative of $|f|$ at $x_0$ is zero.

Comment: I think you should motivate why the limit is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)\ne 0$. because $f$ is continuous, all $f(y)$ have the same sign in a neightbourhood of x.
Due to this we have:

${f(x) - f(x+\epsilon)\over\epsilon}= {|f(x)| - |f(x+\epsilon)|\over\epsilon}*\operatorname{sign}(f(x))$ , which converges due to the differentiability of $ |f|$.

If $f(x)=0$

${f(x) - f(x+\epsilon)\over\epsilon} = {f(x+\epsilon)\over\epsilon}$
${f(x+\epsilon)\over\epsilon}\in[{|f(x+\epsilon)|\over-\epsilon},{|f(x+\epsilon)|\over\epsilon}]$ actually it´s inbetween those two.
Because the interval converges (|f| is differentiable), f is differentiable